# `curl` from a Docker container's network namespace produces different results than `curl` from the container itself

Tags: linux, docker, dns, linux-namespaces

I've set up a Docker container with the `ubuntu` image. I get different results when I `curl` from the Docker container than when I enter the container's network namespace and try the same command. What's taking place here?

```sh
# Set up the container
docker run -d -it --name mycontainer ubuntu
docker exec mycontainer apt update
docker exec mycontainer apt install -y curl

# Run curl but get two different outputs
docker exec mycontainer curl http://yahoo.com
    # => redirect
PID=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' mycontainer)
sudo nsenter -n -t $PID curl http://yahoo.com
    # => curl: (6) Could not resolve host: yahoo.com
```

**Why is dns not working from the network namespace when it appears to work from the container?** Likewise, I fail to get dns info when I `nslookup` or `dig` from the namespace but succeed when I do it from the container.

When in the network namespace, I can check the dns, and I get the same values as I do when checking from my host:

```sh
sudo nsenter -n -t $PID nmcli dev show | grep DNS
# => IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.76.152.1
# => IP4.DNS[2]:                             208.76.152.9
# => IP4.DNS[3]:                             192.168.68.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run :

```
sudo nsenter -n -t $PID ...
```

You use the container's network namespace, but you use host's DNS resolution mechanism.

Try to put (one by one) following entries in your host's /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 192.168.68.1
nameserver 208.76.152.1
nameserver 208.76.152.9
```

to see if it improves.

Comment: It produces no change in behaviour. I don't find that surprising, though, because in my initial experiments, I get those nameserver values when checking my DNS from the host.

Comment: In the container, `/etc/resolv.conf` holds only 2 lines: `nameserver 127.0.0.11` and
`options edns0 trust-ad ndots:0`. I'm not sure what it's doing for dns resolution.

Comment: What are `nameserver`s in your host's /etc/resolv.conf ?  You can also try to put `nameserver 127.0.0.11` in your host's /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Here's my host's `/etc/resolv.conf`: https://pastebin.com/DEbEFDij. It looks rather similar to the container's. I find that adding `nameserver 127.0.0.11` to my host's `/etc/resolv.conf` does indeed make my curl command work. But trying public nameservers `8.8.8.8` or `208.67.222.222` does not. Have you any idea why this is?

Comment: `8.8.8.8` works in my host, container and nsenter. What do you get when you do `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` succeeds (0% packet loss) from my host, the container, and the namespace. From the latter two, the output specifies the IP address of the gateway (another container at 172.19.0.2): `From 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 172.19.0.1)`. Still, adding it as a nameserver doesn't appear to curl executions from the namespace.

Comment: If you can paste the result of `docker inspect mycontainer`, I'll take a further look.

Comment: Thanks, Philippe. Here's my `docker inspect` for this container: https://pastebin.com/Run4zUpE. And here's `docker inspect` for the mitmproxy which I've set as the default gateway for that container: https://pastebin.com/Uw9RnJHq.